# Calling multiple H2O dataframes as input in python multiprocess

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, h2o

I am trying to use multiprocessing in python (version 3.6.8) where 2 tables are to be called as input in a function. Within the function I fit models through h2o. Here is my code:

```
def innerFold(params, feats, target, h2o_train_inner, h2o_test_inner, outer_fold, inner_fold):

    inner_scores = []

    for param in params:

        counter = param.get('counter')
        del param['counter']

        print('parameter combination: ', param)
        print('COUNTER: ', counter)

        #define model and fit
        gbm = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(stopping_rounds = 5,
                                           stopping_metric = 'rmse',
                                           stopping_tolerance = 1e-4,
                                           seed = random_state,
                                           **param)

        print('TRAINING STARTS....')
        gbm.train(x = feats,
                  y = target,
                  training_frame = h2o_train_inner)


        score = gbm.model_performance(h2o_test_inner).r2()
        pd_scores = pd_scores.append({'outer_fold': int(outer_fold),
                                      'inner_fold': int(inner_fold),
                                      'score': score,
                                      'param_idx': int(counter)},
                                     ignore_index=True)

        inner_scores.append(gbm.model_performance(h2o_test_inner).r2())

    return pd_scores
```

I split 'params' argument into 5 as to be processed by 5 different cores and the rest of the arguments should be identical. To this end, I split 'params' as below:

```
df0 = np.array_split(param_combs,5)[0] 
df1 = np.array_split(param_combs,5)[1] 
df2 = np.array_split(param_combs,5)[2] 
df3 = np.array_split(param_combs,5)[3] 
df4 = np.array_split(param_combs,5)[4]
```

And introduce them as follows:

```
args = [(df0, feats, target, h2o_train_inner, h2o_test_inner, outer_fold, inner_fold), 
        (df1, feats, target, h2o_train_inner, h2o_test_inner, outer_fold, inner_fold), 
        (df2, feats, target, h2o_train_inner, h2o_test_inner, outer_fold, inner_fold),
        (df3, feats, target, h2o_train_inner, h2o_test_inner, outer_fold, inner_fold),
        (df4, feats, target, h2o_train_inner, h2o_test_inner, outer_fold, inner_fold)]
```

,where feats, target, h2o_train_inner, h2o_test_inner, outer_fold, inner_fold are type of list (containing dictionaries), string, h2o dataframe, h2o dataframe, int, int, respectively.

Eventually, I start the process as below:

```
p = mp.Pool(processes=5)
pool_results = p.starmap(innerFold, args)
```

And I get:

> TypeError: **new**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'keyvals'

It seems the number of arguments is OK. What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** Apparently the problem stems from H2O dataframes. If I convert them to pandas df, it works. Any idea how I can directly use H2O df?

**EDIT2:** As far as I understand, arguments sent to the function (e.g. innerFold above) are pickled. Since h2o object cannot be pickled, the function worked after it had been converted to pandas df.